# I have a 1999 yamaha r1 and it bogs out really bad

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, cranks-wont-run, vacuum-leak

So I've cleaned the carbs twice on this bike and its like it's not getting enough fuel because it will only run on starting fluid and I've cleaned the tank and got new hoses and still the same problem and now my start button wont work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of anything about motorcycles, but I assume it's a gravity feed instead of using a fuel pump. If you have the hoses disconnected from the carb, does gas come out freely if you pour some in the tank? Also there might be some sort of sintered bronze filter in the thing you connect the hose to that you might have overlooked when cleaning the carbs.